# Sphinx search: how to set matching mode to SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2

Tags: c#, sphinx

I am using sphinx from C# through mysql connection.
How can I set matching mode to SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 through mysql client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SphinxQL is Extended Match Mode by default, you don't need to 'set' it.